# Including another deflate to ZopfliPNG

Tags: c++, zopfli

I'm currently studying programmation and I'm trying to add [This library](https://github.com/ebiggers/libdeflate) to [ZopfliPNG](https://github.com/google/zopfli/blob/master/src/zopflipng/zopflipng_lib.cc#L46). I would like to use it instead of Zopfli. I tried to change to this but it's not working :

```
unsigned CustomPNGDeflate(unsigned char** out, size_t* outsize,
                          const unsigned char* in, size_t insize,
                          const LodePNGCompressSettings* settings) {

            int compression_level = 12;

            struct libdeflate_compressor* compressor;

            compressor = libdeflate_alloc_compressor(compression_level);

            libdeflate_deflate_compress(compressor, in, insize, out, outsize);

            libdeflate_free_compressor(compressor);

            return 0;
}
```

During compilation, I have this :

```
error: invalid conversion from 'size_t* {aka unsigned int*}' to 'size_t {aka unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]
  libdeflate_deflate_compress(compressor, in, insize, out, outsize);

libdeflate.h:65:1:
note: initializing argument 5 of 'size_t libdeflate_deflate_compress(libdeflate_compressor*, const void*, size_t, void*, size_t)'
 libdeflate_deflate_compress(struct libdeflate_compressor *compressor,

make: *** [bin] Error 1
```

Maybe I'm not doing the right stuff here. Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

`outsize` is a `size_t *` but `libdeflate_deflate_compress` is expecting a `size_t`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is that possible do to something about that to make this working ?

Comment: Yes, you need to dereference the pointer to `outsize`. Change `libdeflate_deflate_compress(compressor, in, insize, out, outsize);` to `libdeflate_deflate_compress(compressor, in, insize, out, *outsize);`

Comment: Yes, i've tried this. No error during compilation but i don't why, it's corrupting files (image is full black most of the time)